# Replace first occurrence of string in access query

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am looking for the access query to replace first occurrence of "." in a string.

```
Example:
A.xcvb.NS
.sdfg.FX

O/P:
A-xcvb.NS
-sdfg.FX
```

Let me know if this is possible in access query.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Access, the Replace function replaces a sequence of characters in a string with another set of characters (a number of times).

Syntax

The syntax for the Replace function is:

Replace ( string1, find, replacement, [start, [count, [compare]]] )
string1 is the string to replace a sequence of characters with another set of characters.

find is the string that will be searched for in string1.

replacement will replace find in string1.

start is optional. This is the position in string1 to begin the search. If this parameter is omitted, the Replace function will begin the search at position 1.

count is optional. This is the number of occurrences to replace. If this parameter is omitted, the Replace function will replace all occurrences of find with replacement.

[Replace function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/replace.php)

Answer (score -1):

Use the built in VBA `Replace` function to replace all instances

```
UPDATE tbl
SET fld = Replace(fld,'.','')
```

To replace only the first instance you will need a custom function instead of the above `Replace` function

```
Public Function ReplaceFirstInstance(str As String, strFind As String, strReplace As String) As String
    Dim pos As Long

    pos = InStr(str, strFind)

    If pos > 0 Then
        Mid(str, pos, 1) = strReplace
    End If
    ReplaceFirstInstance = str

End Function
```

Comment: Is there a way to write query without using VBA?

Comment: You could use : `iif(Instr(fld,".")>0,Left(fld,Instr(fld,".")-1) & Mid(fld,Instr(fld,".")+1),fld)` However I would recommend using VBA both for clarity and performance.

Answer (score -1):

E Mett's solution didn't work for me...

```
Public Function ReplaceFirstInstance(str As String, strFind As String, strReplace As String) As String
    Dim pos As Long

    pos = InStr(str, strFind)

    If pos > 0 Then
        ReplaceFirstInstance = Left(str, pos - 1) & strReplace & Mid(str, pos + Len(strFind))
        'Mid(str, pos, 1) = strReplace
    Else
        ReplaceFirstInstance = str
    End If


End Function
```

Comment: If you only had minor change to make to my answer, you should have edited it instead of copying it! Anyway, could you perhaps explain for which case my solution did not work for you.

Comment: The way you have done it, if there is no instance of the FIND string the function will return an empty string!

Comment: @E Mett, you are right I forgot to return the original string in case it didnt find anything. It was causing issues in my program :P